# Don't render component on specific route

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

I have a React-based web application that utilizes React Router to map pages to different URLs:

```
export const Container = () => (
    <div>
        <SideNav/>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/login" component={LoginView} />
                <Route path="/route1" component={RouteOne} />
                <Route path="/route2" component={RouteTwo} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

When any route gets hit, the sidebar gets rendered as well as the appropriate view. However, I am trying to build the layout such that for certain routes (such as "login"), the `SideNav` doesn't get rendered and the component (in this case, `LoginView`) is the only thing that gets rendered. In other words, `LoginView` should take over the `div` and be the only child of the top `div`.

Is there anyway this can be done?

Comment: You can read up on this demo: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar, which allows you to have dynamic sidebar on different route

Answer (score 6):

According to [react-router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string):

> path: string Any valid URL path that path-to-regexp understands.

[path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) understand a string, array of strings, or a regular expression.

**Array of routes:**

State which routes will render the `SideNav` as well ([Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lx48vk9lol)):

```
  <Route path={['/route1', '/route2']} component={SideNav} />
```

**RegExp:**

Another option is to show the `SideNav` only if the path doesn't contain a certain word ([working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zjrk7606x)):

```
  <Route path={/^(?!.*login).*$/} component={SideNav} />
```

And in your code:

```
export const Container = () => (
    <div>
        <Route path={['/route1', '/route2']} component={SideNav} />
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/login" component={LoginView} />
                <Route path="/route1" component={RouteOne} />
                <Route path="/route2" component={RouteTwo} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but how would I have it render both the SideNav and the main view in the routes where both should show?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach (I am not sure about this but I faced the same problem and this is how I fixed it, but I admit it's less cleaner than what **Ori Drori** proposed):

In your **SideNav** component :

```
import React from "react";
import {useLocation} from "react-router"

export const SideNav = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const show = !location.pathname.includes("login");

  return (
    <>
       {show && (<YourLoginComponentCode /> }
    </>
  )
}
```